# Create a child object based on a parent one

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm developing a DB where you at first register as a regular `User` and subsequently become a `Driver`. I'd like to create a `Driver` object in SQL-Alchemy based on existing `User` object. How can I achieve that?

Suppose that the `User` table already has a user with ID=3. Now we would like to add a `Driver` based on that user.

Here are classes that I used:

```py
# Base class
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(MAX_NAME_LENGTH), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(MAX_SURNAME_LENGTH), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(MAX_EMAIL_LENGTH), nullable=False, unique=True)


# Child class
class Driver(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.__tablename__ + '.id'), primary_key=True)
    photo_url= db.Column(db.String(MAX_URL_LENGTH), nullable=False)
    # ...
```

```py
# we can easily add a new User
user = User(first_name='Martin', last_name='Smith', email='m.smith@gmail.com')
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
# But this code will create a new user and assign it to that driver instance!
# driver = Driver(# Will require fields of both User and Driver class #)
```

I expect to find some method for taking parent object and extending it with child's properties. Something like:

```py
user_from_db = db.session.query(User).filter_by(User.id == 3).first()
driver = Driver(photo_url='/your_url/', based_on=user_from_db)
# And now driver has all properties of 'user_from_db'
# Furthermore, SQL-Alchemy would create a row only in `Driver` table
```

How can I accomplish that using SQL-Alchemy inheritance?

Comment: Have you read [Mapping Class Inheritance Hierarchies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html)?

Answer (score 1):

First I recommend making the following changes:

The autoincrement field is to leave the task of assigning an id to the database.

For all relationship (OneToMany, ManyToMany or OneToOne) you need to specify a db.relationship in the parent class. [Read this](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships).

And `__tablename__` is optional, but sometimes flask throw an error if this is not assigned.

```py
# Base class
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(MAX_NAME_LENGTH), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(MAX_SURNAME_LENGTH), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(MAX_EMAIL_LENGTH), nullable=False, unique=True)
    driver = db.relationship('Driver', backref='driver', lazy=True)


# Child class
class Driver(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'driver'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    photo_url= db.Column(db.String(MAX_URL_LENGTH), nullable=False)
    # ...
```

```py
user = User(first_name='Martin', last_name='Smith', email='m.smith@gmail.com')
db.session.add(user) # first we create a user and add him to the current session
db.session.flush() # here we says that db.session.add(user) is a pending transaction. More info [here][1]
driver = Driver(id=user.id, photo_url='/your_url/')
# and we pass as driver id the id of user previously created
db.session.add(driver) # add driver to current session
db.session.commit() # commits those changes to the database.
```

Comment: Thanks for response! So, you recommend that I use `relationship` rather than model inheritance in that case? I also thought about that. But is it possible to solve my problem with ORM inheritance? Or I do have some misunderstanding about ORM Inheritance usage?

Comment: I don't say that 'relationship' is better than inheritance because I don't know the pros and cons of each one.
Perhaps it is possible to solve it with inheritance, but I came up with a solution using a foreignkey as primarykey and respect everything you raise.